# Weblogic server login credentials pass to home page to be reused

Tags: javascript, html, weblogic

I am new to this site . My question is below.

I created a login page (html) that will call the weblogic server for authentication. How can I reuse that credentials to be used for my other web pages?  In the login page, I called action j_security_check with method of "POST". Thank you

Comment: so let me get this straigt: you want to check in an another web page if the user is logged in or not?

Comment: Welcome to SO ;) Please read this article on [how to ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). This would include a proper description of what you are trying to achieve, your code (or the relevant snippets) as well as your efforts showing what you have tried so far and possible error messages.

Comment: Hello .  I will use that credentials to access another server that will send message to a QUE. Basically, I have a login screen. Then after the user successfully login, in another web page, the user will have a enterable form ( html) then in that page, it will have a submit button that will send message to the QUE. My problem is I want to reuse the login credentials entered from the login screen to login successfully to the server (backend). But since the method I used in the login was to call the web logic server , I cannot find a way to pass the login data(username and password). Thank you

Comment: sounds like SSO (Single sign on), no ?

Comment: i am not sure what that is but yeah, you will be using your credentials in all of the process back end. My back end is in JAVA